# Timeseries data object for 1 month R

Tags: r, time-series

I have 20 days data for the month of Oct. This data is from different departments but have the same columns. 
There are 46 variables (columns) and looks like this:

```
 Date X24K.Equivalent.Plan X24K.Equivalent.Act Plan.Rep.WS Act.Rep.WS Rep.WS.Var Plan.Rep.Intakes
1 2014-10-18                 29.0                28.8        2463       2447        -16              568
2 2014-10-19                 29.6                31.0        2513       2633        120              461
3 2014-10-20                 33.8                35.4        2869       3013        144             1159
4 2014-10-21                 36.6                35.9        3115       3054        -61             1146
5 2014-10-22                 35.3                34.7        2999       2953        -46             1126
6 2014-10-23                 31.9                33.4        2714       2842        128             1124
```

Note i am just showing 7 columns only.

I want to convert this monthly data into time series object so that i can do some timeseries analysis etc.
The problem I have is:

1- Same data comes from 4 other business units, do i have to create 4 timeseries objects? if yes then how can I plot variation/difference in performance on the same time series plot?

2- I can not plot more than 10 variables :/

I tried the following:

```
#convert date column into date format and add id
library(lubridate)
bvg1$Date = dmy(bvg1$Date)

> bvg1
        Date X24K.Equivalent.Plan X24K.Equivalent.Act Plan.Rep.WS Act.Rep.WS Rep.WS.Var Plan.Rep.Intakes
1 2014-10-18                 29.0                28.8        2463       2447        -16              568
2 2014-10-19                 29.6                31.0        2513       2633        120              461
3 2014-10-20                 33.8                35.4        2869       3013        144             1159
4 2014-10-21                 36.6                35.9        3115       3054        -61             1146
5 2014-10-22                 35.3                34.7        2999       2953        -46             1126
6 2014-10-23                 31.9                33.4        2714       2842        128             1124
7 2014-10-24                 29.0                31.9        2468       2714        246             1106
```

if i convert it to timeseries:

```
ts_bvg1 = ts(bvg1_withoutID)
```

It shows a weird date:

```
Date X24K.Equivalent.Plan X24K.Equivalent.Act Plan.Rep.WS Act.Rep.WS Rep.WS.Var Plan.Rep.Intakes
1 1413590400                 29.0                28.8        2463       2447        -16              568
2 1413676800                 29.6                31.0        2513       2633        120              461
3 1413763200                 33.8                35.4        2869       3013        144             1159
4 1413849600                 36.6                35.9        3115       3054        -61             1146
5 1413936000                 35.3                34.7        2999       2953        -46             1126
6 1414022400                 31.9                33.4        2714       2842        128             1124
7 1414108800                 29.0                31.9        2468       2714        246             1106
```

If i do the following:

```
ts_bvg1 = ts(bvg1_withoutID, start=2014)
```

still shows the date in that weird format but adds year from 2014 - 2020 etc.

```
> ts_bvg1
Time Series:
Start = 2014 
End = 2020 
Frequency = 1 
           Date X24K.Equivalent.Plan X24K.Equivalent.Act Plan.Rep.WS Act.Rep.WS Rep.WS.Var Plan.Rep.Intakes
2014 1413590400                 29.0                28.8        2463       2447        -16              568
2015 1413676800                 29.6                31.0        2513       2633        120              461
2016 1413763200                 33.8                35.4        2869       3013        144             1159
2017 1413849600                 36.6                35.9        3115       3054        -61             1146
2018 1413936000                 35.3                34.7        2999       2953        -46             1126
2019 1414022400                 31.9                33.4        2714       2842        128             1124
2020 1414108800                 29.0                31.9        2468       2714        246             1106
```

How can I force it to treat observations as daily and not monthly or yearly?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for showing the data shape. It's really great if we have reproducible examples though, is this data public? By he way, your weird date is probably seconds since the Unix epoch

Comment: Hi Thank you for your comment. No this dataset is internal to my organisation and I can not share it with outside world sorry. Any idea how to resolve my issues. Probably you are right about the weird date format.

Comment: I understand, this is very commonly the problem (confidential data). It's a pain, but if you want people to be able to help you on here, the offically recommended approach is to reproduce your error with public data then let us help you using the public data. BTW, I was able to successfully convert those timestamps tho. Copy one of those weird dates and paste it in here http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by using the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf) package.

I did the following:

```
library(zoo)
ts_bvg1 = zoo(bvg1, order.by=bvg1$Date)

> ts_bvg1
           Date       X24K.Equivalent.Plan X24K.Equivalent.Act Plan.Rep.WS Act.Rep.WS Rep.WS.Var Plan.Rep.Intakes
2014-10-18 2014-10-18 29.0                 28.8                2463        2447       -16         568            
2014-10-19 2014-10-19 29.6                 31.0                2513        2633       120         461            
2014-10-20 2014-10-20 33.8                 35.4                2869        3013       144        1159            
2014-10-21 2014-10-21 36.6                 35.9                3115        3054       -61        1146            
2014-10-22 2014-10-22 35.3                 34.7                2999        2953       -46        1126            
2014-10-23 2014-10-23 31.9                 33.4                2714        2842       128        1124            
2014-10-24 2014-10-24 29.0                 31.9                2468        2714       246        1106
```

The issue is now with plotting this data as a time series.
This is what I did:

```
> plot(ts_bvg1$X24K.Equivalent.Plan, col="red")
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value
```

I have tried different columns and getting the same error.

if I print `ts_bvg1$X24K.Equivalent.Plan` That's how it looks like:

```
> ts_bvg1$X24K.Equivalent.Plan
2014-10-18 2014-10-19 2014-10-20 2014-10-21 2014-10-22 2014-10-23 2014-10-24 
      29.0       29.6       33.8       36.6       35.3       31.9       29.0
```

Any idea how to plot it now? or plot it with other parameters on the same graph???